# How to loop through lists on another .py file?

Tags: python

I'm very new to code, first of all, So, I have a .py file that contains 2 lists of things. One of the lists is a dictionary nested inside a list. My assignment is to import that file into my main script and append those lists into a new list inside a function so that I can call it and display the information to the user. I'm not quite sure how to do that. Could someone please help me figure this out?

Example:

food.py

```
TYPES = [
'vegetables'
'raw food'
'cooked food'
]

INGREDIENTS = [{
    'name' : 'sugar'
    'taste' : 'sweet'

    'name' : 'lemon'
    'taste' : 'sour'

    }
]
```

main.py

```
import food


 def cooking():
```

What I have to do is append the name, tase into their own category.

Output Example when calling `def_cooking()`:

```
Food Types: vegetables
total ingredients: 2

ingredients:
sugar, lemon
```

Comment: Your `INGREDIENTS` input is invalid, and your output example is unclear (in the context of how it should be derived from the input).

Comment: The `food.py` you've provided has errors and doesn't make sense. The main error is that all the key/value pairs are in a single dictionary, while it looks like they should be in at least two dictionaries. It doesn't make sense because it doesn't relate the ingredients to the food types, even though it appears that this is what you need to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `sugar, lemon` output is not possible given that a dictionary cannot contain multiple of the same key, so you'll need to sort that out.

See

```
In [2]: INGREDIENTS = [{
   ...:     'name' : 'sugar',
   ...:     'taste' : 'sweet',
   ...:
   ...:     'name' : 'lemon',
   ...:     'taste' : 'sour',
   ...:     }
   ...: ]

In [3]: INGREDIENTS
Out[3]: [{'name': 'lemon', 'taste': 'sour'}]
```

Maybe you just didn't copy the close and open brackets between sweet and lemon?

---

Regarding the question about importing a list

```
from food import INGREDIENTS, TYPES

print(TYPES)  # for example
```

or

```
import food

print(food.TYPES)  # for example
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

---

From there you can loop, append, etc. once you figure out the logic and data structures.

Comment: Thank you! your answer just saves me tons of times. I really appreciate your help. Right now, I'm stuck at one more thing if I were to append the names of ingredients to a list. Could you help me out with how should I loop through those? 

The output should look something like:

    ingredients:
        sugar, lemon

Comment: Maybe read over the sections on lists and loops? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: And like I said, it's not possible to get `sugar, lemon` because sugar never exists in your list to begin with. You need to fix your data structures, but I don't know your requirements like if you were given that to begin with

Comment: That's right I forgot to type the brackets. Anyways, I finally managed to get those names in a list and display them successfully. Thanks for your help again!